# Why can't I modify a file with UltraEdit?

Tags: permissions, sudo

I just installed UltraEdit for Ubuntu, and I can open files and modify them, but when I try to save them I don’t have permissions.

Using the command line and Vim, I can `sudo` and make all the changes I want, but I am not sure how to get administrator privileges using a GUI.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *secret* to this is the command `gksudo` or `gksu`

> gksu  is a frontend to su and gksudo is a frontend to sudo.  Their
>   primary purpose is to run graphical commands that need  root  without  the
>   need to run an X terminal emulator and using su directly.

You only need to use `gksudo` when editing system files:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

So, for example, `gksudo uex` will prompt you for your password

[image]

If you want to invoke this in a GUI manner simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type your command i.e.

[image]

Now - just to make clear - I'm assuming that `ultraedit` is the linux variant of the editor and you are not attempting to use the windows version of `ultraedit` running through wine.

My experience is that running anything with root privileges is a definite no-no - as explained in the [Wine Wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ).

Comment: I'm not sure why all the comments disappeared but it is indeed the Linux version of UltraEdit, thanks for your help! This is exactly what i needed

Comment: ... just me tidying up :)